# HTTP server send new request with response

Tags: c, sockets, server

My task is to implement simple HTTP server. Server send strange response. This output of Wireshark.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1

Host: 127.0.0.1:8080

Connection: keep-alive

    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Domain</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #f0f0f2;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

        }
        div {
            width: 600px;
            margin: 5em auto;
            padding: 50px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 1em;
        }
        a:link, a:visited {
            color: #38488f;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        @media (max-width: 700px) {
            body {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            div {
                width: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-radius: 0;
                padding: 1em;
            }
        }
        </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
    <div>
        <h1>Example Domain</h1>
        <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
        domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
    Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
    Connection: keep-alive
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
    Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
    Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
```

As you see there is new request at the end of response. I don't understand why this is happen. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: HTTP 1.1 allows reusing the same connection for multiple requests.

Comment: Are you talking about keep-alive attribute?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is controlled via keep-alive but I would guess yes.

Comment: Keep-alives are required in order to reuse the connection. In HTTP 1.1, keep-alives are enabled by default, unless the client or server explicitly state otherwise in the `Connection` header. But also consider HTTP pipelining, where the client can send a new request (even multiple requests) without waiting for a previous response first. The server still has to process the requests and send the responses in order, though (HTTP 2.0 allows out-of-order responses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the browser automatically checks the Favicon presence.

Comment: But is it ok that new request is in the end of response?

Comment: @МаксимБелан Where else do you expect it?

Comment: Yes. The request is in HTTP 1.1 version, and moreover using the Connection Keep-Alive header, and the connection is kept opened and allowed for several requests.